# What is the relation between Mar-Vell and Yon-Rogg?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

Watched the *Captain Marvel* movie recently. Got this doubt after seeing it.

What is the relation between Mar-Vell and Yon-Rogg?

Comment: Got *what* doubt? What do you mean by relation?

Comment: @TylerH I meant how in the fiction is Mar-Vell associated with Yon-Rogg. Like what links both these characters.

Comment: By fiction do you mean the comics? Or the movie? You're asking a question based on a large presumption, namely that there *is* a link between the character. You ought to clarify *that*, otherwise the question is far too broad as we'd have to guess what you mean by 'links'.

Comment: @TylerH I watched the film last week and I didn't quite understand how the characters (Mar Vell and Yon Rogg) have a role in Captain Marvel's life. I have not read the comics. I watched the film only .

Comment: Thanks for that clarification; it seems that's a distinct question from what you were appearing to ask, though, and what was explained in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much context is given about this in the movies, so this answer mostly draws from the comics. While the specifics probably differ, the general tone of their relationship seem to be the same.

Mar-Vell was a spy who secretly defected from the Kree empire, while Yon-Rogg was a soldier in the Kree Imperial Army who stayed loyal. They had been on several missions together before, and on several of them Mar-Vell impressed their superiors. Mar-Vell was also the target of a chrush from another Kree named Una, making Yon-Rogg jealous. Even before the defection, Yon-Rogg was jealous of his* success and accomplishments and tried to have him killed. After the betrayal was uncovered, Yon-Rogg was part of the mission to hunt him down and execute him, and was happy to do so.

*Mar-Vell is male in the comics

Sources: My memories of the comics refreshed by the [marvel](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Yon-Rogg_(Earth-616)) [wiki.](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mar-Vell_(Earth-616))

Comment: @Pelinore I didn't say Carol Danvers is male in the comics, neither did I say that "Captain Marvel" is male - I said Mar-Vell is male. Captain Marvel is a title that has been carried by half a dozen individuals of different genders and species. The first one was named Mar-Vell, who was a specific individual who was, in fact, male in he comics but female in the MCU. The question asks for "Mar-Vell", not Captain Marvel. None of this has anything to do with DC comics.

Comment: @Pelinore "Mar-Vell" is a specific Kree individual in the Marvel universes, who was the first to use the mantle of Captain Marvel.  Carol Danvers is a different, human individual who also uses the mantle of Captain Marvel, with most versions getting that name from her relationship with "Mar-Vell".

Comment: @Pelinore I'm getting very confused by what you are saying, but I'll try to clarify a bit more. There **is** a Mar-Vell in the 2019 Captain Marvel movie that is female, she also goes by the name Wendy Lawson. She corresponds to her comic namesake in several ways, but never uses the "Captain Marvel" name. https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mar-Vell_(Earth-199999)

Comment: @Pelinore Movie spoiler follows: A female version of Mar-Vell is in the movie, and she encounters Yon-Rogg during the plot.  That is who the question is about, not Carol Danvers.

Comment: [Aha!](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2019/03/226154/captain-marvel-movie-changes-from-comics) _"About that original Captain Marvel… the Captain Marvel movie actually does a great job of sticking to the story of the original Captain Marvel, aka Mar-Vell, from the comics. But there’s one massive twist: **the MCU has gender swapped Mar-Vell**, changing the Kree military officer from a man to a woman."_ somehow I'd missed any reference to that ~ my apologies [face-plant] ~ have a [+]